# google maps satellite xyz ferme

Tags: elevation

I am looking for a source of buildings elevation, preferably stored as 2D images (for each pixel, the intensity corresponds to the altitude in that XY). Considering the case of NY, it would be a XY projection (in greyscale) of [this](https://cesiumjs.org/NewYork/index.html?view=-74.01971723586352%2C40.691335259906374%2C753.3113887561028%2C21.27879875496051%2C-21.343905324886247%2C0.07169526875947171) map. Do you know where I can find such material, in case it's available? And/or, is there any easy way to convert GIS data formats into images?

Comment: for cesium you will need CityGML for the 3D format > your in luck as New York has Open Data and it is available to download > https://www1.nyc.gov/site/doitt/initiatives/3d-building.page (848mb)

Comment: Thanks! What is the easiest way to translate CityGML to XYZ, in your opinion?